# Ubuntu - Add user to samba via shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, samba

I want to add a user to samba on my Linux Ubuntu Server.
I used following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
username=$1
pass=$2
(echo "$pass"; echo "$pass") | smbpasswd -s -a $username
```

Than I run this command:

```
sudo /bin/bash sambaAddUser.sh test 1234
```

And I get this error:

```
.ailed to add entry for user test
```

I created the user previously with useradd, so this is not the problem.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I created the file in windows and transfered it to my linux system, so there where problems with the line endings.

Using this command I solved it:

```
dos2unix sambaAddUser.sh
```